# How could I execute a jar from another program and display the results in another?

Tags: java, jar, return, executable-jar

I have 2 java programs. One is an executable jar that will return a value of hello world to a console. Listed below..

```
public class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        helloWorldSubRoutine();

    }

    public static void helloWorldSubRoutine () {

        String helloWorld = "Hello there!";
          System.out.println(helloWorld);

    }

}
```

The other program is a simple jframe with a label that I want it to display a return or string from another jar.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what's really scary, when an idea works first time...you're left wondering what you did wrong...

The basic idea is to execute a new JVM and read the output from that process.  To do this you can use a `ProcessBuilder` and execute `java` directly.

This example will require `java` to be in the execution path to work.  Also, the Jar is trying to run was in the `dist` directory, you may need to change this ;)

**Executor**

This will launch Java, execute the required Jar file and read the response.

```
public class RunJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "dist/RunJava.jar");
        pb.redirectErrorStream();
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            p.waitFor();
            isr.join();

            System.out.println("Process said [" + isr.getText() + "]");
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class InputStreamReader extends Thread {

        private InputStream is;
        private String text;

        public InputStreamReader(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            start();
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
            int value = -1;
            try {
                while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char)value);
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
                sb.append(exp.getMessage());
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        }

    }

}
```

**Main**

The "main" class that was been executed (and whose result we were reading...)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from the other side!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the jar to your project and then call the method that returns what you are looking for. In this way you are treating the jar as another class that you cant see the implementation of.

Keep in mind this wont capture text written to the console.

Comment: That is a good idea, however I need it to be separate from the project altogether, because outside sources may create a jar without the source and need this program I am writing.