# Java run Process unable to get standard out

Tags: java, process

I have my code below. I am trying to run my ruby script and get the standard out, I don't really need standard error in this case. For some reason, I could not get any output at all in my production host, and I only get empty string. The same code works fine in my desktop. If I run my ruby script myself, I could get output from it. My ruby script only has a puts statement for now. Any one know the reason? Is it that I need to some kind of block to wait for the ruby script to finish?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("ruby", "tests.rb");
Process process = processBuilder.start();

BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Line is: " + line);
    output.append(line + "\n");
}

bufferReader.close();
return output.toString();
```

I have redhat machine running zsh.

Comment: Does you script send any new line characters? I would also suggest you try and have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101387/how-could-i-execute-a-jar-from-another-program-and-display-the-results-in-anothe/15104408#15104408) for ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the process's output stream (its standard input), and you should probably merge the output and error streams. You might think you don't want them both but you might be wrong, and if the process produces enough unread error output it will stall.